# PHP String extraction from another string

Tags: php, string, delimiter, extract

I have a string like this:

```
S="str1|str2|str3"
```

I want extract another string from S which will contains only

```
t="str1|str2"
```

where `|` is the delimiter

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "str1|str2|str3";
$pieces = explode( '|', $string); // Explode on '|'
array_pop( $pieces); // Pop off the last element
$t = implode( '|', $pieces); // Join the string back together with '|'
```

Alternatively, use string manipulation:

```
$string = "str1|str2|str3";
echo substr( $string, 0, strrpos( $string, '|'));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NuzOyK)

Comment: @Zonta You're quite welcome - If the input string is only going to be like your example, use the second version (string manipulation), as it's far more efficient.

Comment: yes, my input string is only going to be like my ex, 
cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
implode("|",  array_slice(explode("|", $s), 0, 2));
```

Not a very flexible solution, but works for your test case.

Alternatively, you can utilise `explode()`'s third param `limit`, like so:

```
implode("|",  explode("|", $s, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'str1|str2|str3';
$t = implode('|', explode('|', $s, -1));
echo $t; // outputs 'str1|str2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [strpos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and  at the [substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

That is the way I would go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

So, get the same string without the last element?

This works:

```
print_r(implode('|', explode('|', 'str1|str2|str3', -1)));
```

Using explode with a negative *limit* so it returns all the string without the last element, and then imploding the elements again.

Answer (score 0):

This example should set you on the right path

```
$str = "str1|str2|str3";
$pcs = explode("|", $str);
echo implode( array_slice($pcs, 0, 2), "|" );
```